# What happens when I use a goto inside a double for?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

To better explain what I'm asking I made a little piece of code. Let's say I have the following:

```
for /l %%i in (1,1,3) do (
    :break
    for /l %%j in (1,1,3) do (
        if "%%i,%%j" equ "2,2" goto :break
        echo(%%i,%%j
    )
)
```

The expected output from the above code would be:

```
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,1
3,1
3,2
3,3
```

But instead, the result I get is the following:

```
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,1
%i,1
%i,2
%i,3
```

This is just an example, it happens with all kind of double `for` loops I use. So, can anyone tell me what does the `goto` actually do that affects so much the outter `for`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GOTO` breaks the for (and if) contexts. So after the first goto execution the outer loop execution is interrupted. As a `FOR` inside a function still have access to an outer for tokens in a subroutine call following workaround can be used:

```
@echo off

for /l %%i in (1,1,3) do (
    call ::funct
)


exit /b %errorlevel%

:funct

    for /l %%j in (1,1,3) do (
        rem ::
        rem :: notice that %%i is accessible inside the FOR
        rem ::
        if "%%i,%%j" equ "2,2" goto break
        echo(%%i,%%j
    )
    :break

exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Comment: Perfectly understood. Thanks!

Comment: That is interesting. that 2,2 and 2,3 never echos.  I thought you could never break a `FOR /L` command like that from the discussion we had about it on DosTips.